# How do you write a vanilla nodejs router without using npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example I have a server.js

```
'use strict';
var http, bunyan, config;

config   = require('config');
http     = require('http');
bunyan   = require('bunyan');

//require('./routes/'); ?

process.env.TZ = 'UTC';
process.env.NODE_ENV =  process.env.NODE_ENV || 'staging';
var environment   = config.get('environment');

var log = bunyan.createLogger({
  name        : 'index',
  level       : 'debug',
  stream      : process.stdout,
  });

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200,
  {'Content-Type'   : 'text/plain'});
});

server.on('error', function(error){
  log.error('Errored with the message: ',error);
  process.exit(1);
});

server.listen(environment.port);
log.info(process.env.NODE_ENV);
log.info('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:'+environment.port+'/');
```

I have three controllers Blog, Todo and Auth It is trivial to do this in restify, express or hapi but how do I write routing file without using any npm packages?

Do I need to write `require(./routes)(server)` ? and then `function routes(server) {} module.exports = routes` ?

Is there a more readable way?

Comment: can I ask why? Is it only for learning puposes

Comment: I wrote a node program without framework, as I don't need it all the other functionalities they offer. but having problems with routes, right now all I have is `require('./../controllers/1.js');`

Comment: 1.js is not a function but rather an extension code, because I cant figure out how to do routing :D

Comment: There are no routes without middleware, you'd have to parse the URL's yourself inside the createServer callback and figure out what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to also import `url` to parse the url, then check the path. From there you can send back what you want, in the code below it is an image from a file:

**Note** this is basically what adeneo has stated in the comment above!

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var path = url.parse(request.url, true).pathname;

  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    if (path === '/hifive') {
      response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'image/jpg'});
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/assets/hifive.jpg', function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        response.end(data, 'utf-8');
      })
    }
    else {
     response.end(404);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Looks great Thank you!